# R for loop in another one

Tags: r, for-loop, plotly

I have a data and I subset part of it:

```
Products      degrees     Year      Value  
1               A         2015      2234751
1               A         2016      1583064
1               A         2017       331248
1               B         2015    174022286
1               B         2016    192980994
1               B         2017     32368003  
2               A         2016     31546895
2               A         2017     56789215
2               B         2016       598752
2               B         2017    145687895
```

And I use `for-loop` and the code is in the following:

```
for(i in unique(data$Products)){
plot_ly(data[data$Products == i,], labels = ~degrees, values = ~value, type = 'pie',
               textposition = 'inside',
               textinfo = 'label+percent',
               insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
               hoverinfo = 'text') %>%
     layout(title = '',
            xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
            yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
}
```

The result in `Products 1` just show `Year 2015`.
I have an idea whether I can use another for-loop in this? So I can get each products and their each year's pie chart.
Thank You.

Comment: you can try to add an interaction of degree and year `interaction(degrees,Year)`

Comment: @Jimbou can you explain in more detail way?

Comment: Not really as your question is not clear for me. 1. In the plot_ly function the `Year column` isn't specified, so why the year `2015` should show up? 2. Do you want to plot both plots (Products 1 and 2) beside each other? 3...

Comment: take `Products 1` as an example. I hope I can have three pie charts(`Year 2015~2017`).

Comment: Do you mean three pie charts per product, so in total 6 charts, e.g. two products x three years?

Comment: close. However, in my data, `Products 2` does not include `Year 2015`. Thus, just 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could plot for each product and year combination the values.

You first define an empty plot via `plot_ly` and then add each pie chart separately and specify its position via `domain`.

[image]

```
data = data.frame(Products=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
 degrees= c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","B","B"),
 year=c(2015,2016,2017,2015,2016,2017,2016,2017,2016,2017),
 value=c(2234751, 1583064, 331248, 174022286, 192980994, 32368003, 31546895, 56789215, 598752, 145687895))


p <- plot_ly()
counter <- 0
total <- nrow(unique(expand.grid(data$Products, data$year)))

for(product in unique(data$Products)) {
  for(year in unique(data[data$Products == product,]$year)) {
    print(product)
    print(year)
    p <- add_pie(p, 
               data=data[(data$Products == product) & (data$year == year),], 
               values = ~value, 
               labels = ~degrees,
               type = 'pie',
               name = paste(product, year),
               domain = list(x = c(counter / total, (counter + 1) / total),
                             y = c(0,1))
    )
    counter <- counter + 1

  }
}

p <- layout(p, 
            title = '',
            xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
            yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
p
```

Comment: oh. very close. However, there are something wrong. Your `label` is `Year` rather than `degrees`, so your plot at left side, it  contains three colors(`Year 2015~2017`), and 4 pie charts because there are 2 products, each contains 2 degrees.

Comment: What I actually want is `Products 1` has 3 pie charts because there are 3 years in `Products 1`, and `Products 2` has 2 pie charts because there are 2 years in `Products 2`. In addition, in `Products 1`'s pie charts, each plot has 2 colors since there are 2 `degrees`